# Error 'Helloworld' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've a react code as shown below which is showing error at Line A `Helloworld is not defined` although its defined at `Line B`.

**React code:**

```
const Helloworld = (props) => {  /* Line B */
    return (
        timezones.map((timezone) => {
            <a onClick = {
                (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    props.onChange(timezone)
                }
            } > timezone < /a>
        })
    )
}


return(
    <VersionPageHolder>
        {
            <Helloworld onChange={(timezone) => {      /* Line A */     
                setSelectedTimezone(timezone);
            }}
            />
        }
        <div>{content.title}</div>
        <div>Version List : </div>
        <div>{
            renderElements(selectedTimezone)
        }</div>
    </VersionPageHolder>
)
```

Comment: remove `{` around `Helloworld` in `line A`

Comment: Like this  ?   `<Helloworld onChange={(timezone) =>     /* Line A */     
                setSelectedTimezone(timezone);
            }
            />`

Comment: yes  with out `{` `}` wrapping apround `<Helloworld  ....../>`

Comment: On removing that, its showing me error. Can you explain me in the answer?

Comment: Is  `Helloworld` component on same file or you are importing ?

Comment: Its at Line B I guess ?

Comment: [check this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bash-jgr94?file=/src/App.js) you were missing return from `map`

Comment: looks like Helloworld and final return is inside the same React component, if like that then change `{
            <Helloworld onChange={(timezone) => {      /* Line A */     
                setSelectedTimezone(timezone);
            }}
            />
        }` to just `{Helloworld()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are not returning any value. You can do like this.
You need to change  bracket after timezone `(timezone) => (`

```
const Helloworld = (props) => {  /* Line B */
    return (
        timezones.map((timezone) => (
            <a onClick = {
                (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    props.onChange(timezone)
                }
            } > timezone < /a>
        ))
    )
}
```

Or you can do like this as well. Just return the component inside map.

```
const Helloworld = (props) => {  /* Line B */
    return (
        timezones.map((timezone) => {
          return (
            <a onClick = {
                (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    props.onChange(timezone)
                }
            } > timezone < /a>
          )
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: @Yadav Hi, I have one more question (not similar) . Its from the same file. I am wondering if you can look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66710837/how-to-show-data-from-database-cms-in-react/