# How to show data from database/cms in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `react code` as shown below in which to pull data from CMS/Database.

**React code:**

```
<div>
   { versionList.map((element,i)=>{ 
   console.log(element); /* Line Z */ 
   return( 
   <ListItem>
      <div key={i}>
         <p>title: {element.title}</p>
         <p>description: {element.description}</p>
         <p>air date: {convertToTimeZone({date: element.air_date_dt},selectedTimezone)}</p>
      </div>
   </ListItem>
   ) }) }
</div>
```

**Line Z** prints the following:

```
air_date_dt: "2021-03-20T11:00:00.000Z"
air_duration_i: "1"
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."
description_en_t: "Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus."
description_fr_t: "Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque."
image: "/versions/en.png"
image_en_s: "/versions/en.png"
image_fr_s: "versions/fr.png"
title: "Hello World"
title_en_t: "Hello World"
title_fr_t: "Bonjour le monde"
```

**Problem Statement:** In my code above, the div inside the `ListItem` doesn't print anything although I am able to show everything at `Line Z`.

Comment: Try with: element?.title, element?.description, etc, and add a key to <ListItem

Comment: @pmiranda I am wondering if you can explain me in an answer. I am not a very strong react developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a warning because the `ListItem` component does not have a key property.

Try to move the key from the `div` to the `ListItem` component.
Another hint should be to check CSS. Make sure you do not have hidden blocks.

Answer (score 0):

At Line Z you are doing a console log which is why you can see the data. The div and the rest of your code in that div is being returned. Depending on where is it is going and what is happening with it could be your problem. Could you please include the code where the return is send the div?

Answer (score 0):

Add a key to the `<ListItem>` and use the `?` in case the `element` object be undefined in the first render:
Try this code:

```
<div>
    { versionList.map((element,i)=>{ 
    console.log(element); /* Line Z */ 
    return( 
    <ListItem key={`list-item-${i}`}>
      <div key={`div-key-${i}`}>
        <p>title: {element?.title}</p>
        <p>description: {element?.description}</p>
        <p>air date: {convertToTimeZone({date: element?.air_date_dt},selectedTimezone)}</p>
      </div>
    </ListItem>
    ) }) }
</div>
```